# What does this wildcard do in this prolog scenario?

Tags: prolog

I've come across this code:

```
connectRow(_,_,0).
connectRow([spot(_,R,_,_)|Spots],R,K) :- K1 is K-1, connectRow(Spots,R,K1).

/*c*/
connectRows([]).
connectRows(Spots) :- 
   connectRow(Spots,_,9),
   skip(Spots,9,Spots1), 
   connectRows(Spots1).
```

How does the wildcard in the connectRow(Spots,_,9) work? How does it know which values to check and how does it know that it checked all the possible values?

Edit: I think I understand why this works but I'd like it if someone could verify this for me:
When I "call" the connectRow with the wildcard it matches the wildcard with the "R" in the connectRow predicate. Could this be it?

Answer (score 2):

The `_` is just like any other variable, except that each one you see is treated as a different variable and Prolog won't show you what it unifies with. There's no special behavior there; if it confuses you about the behavior, just invent a completely new variable and put it in there to see what it does.

Let's talk about how Prolog deals with variables. Here's an experiment you can follow along with that should undermine unhelpful preconceived notions if you happen to have them.

```
?- length([2,17,4], X)
X = 3.
```

A lot of Prolog looks like this and it's easy to fall into the trap of thinking that there are designated "out" variables that work like return values and designated "in" variables that work like parameters. After all:

```
?- length([2,17,4], 3).
true.

?- length([2,17,4], 5).
false.
```

Here we begin to see that something interesting is happening. A faulty intuition would be that Prolog is somehow keeping track of the input and output variables and "checking" in this case. That's not what's happening though, because unification is more general than that. Observe:

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_G2184, _G2187, _G2190].
```

We've now turned the traditional parameter/return value on its head: Prolog knows that X is a list three items long, but doesn't know what the items actually are. Believe it or not, this technique is frequently used to generate variables when you know how many you need but you don't need to have them individually named.

```
?- length(X, Y).
X = [],
Y = 0 ;

X = [_G2196],
Y = 1 ;

X = [_G2196, _G2199],
Y = 2 ;

X = [_G2196, _G2199, _G2202],
Y = 3
```

It happens that the definition of length is very general and Prolog can use it to generate lists along with their lengths. This kind of behavior is part of what makes Prolog so good at "generate and test" solutions. You define your problem logically and Prolog should be able to generate logically sound values to test.

All of this variation springs from a pretty simple definition of length:

```
length([], 0).
length([_|Rest], N1) :-
  length(Rest, N0), 
  succ(N0, N1).
```

The key is to not read this like a procedure for calculating length but instead to see it as a logical relation between lists and numbers. The definition is inductive, relating the empty list to 0 and a list with some items to 1 + the length of the remainder of the list. The engine that makes this work is called unification.

In the first case, `length([2,17,4], X)`, the value [17,4] is unified with Rest, N0 with 2 and N1 with 3. The process is recursive. In the final case, X is unified with [] and Y with 0, which leads naturally to the next case where we have some item and Y is 1, and the fact that the variable representing the item in the list doesn't have anything in particular to unify with doesn't matter because the value of that variable is never used.

Looking at your problem we see the same sort of recursive structure. The predicates are quite complex, so let's take them in pieces.

```
connectRow(_, _, 0).
```

This says `connectRow(X, Y, 0)` is true, regardless of X and Y. This is the base case.

```
connectRow([spot(_, R, _, _)|Spots], R, K) :-
```

This rule is matching a list of spots of a particular structure, presuming the first spot's second value (R) matches the second parameter.

```
K1 is K-1, connectRow(Spots, R, K1).
```

The body of this clause is essentially recurring on decrementing K, the third parameter.

It's clear now that this is basically going to generate a list that looks like `[spot(_, R, _, _), spot(_, R, _, _), ... spot(_, R, _, _)]` with length = K and no particular values in the other three positions for `spot`. And indeed that's what we see when we test it:

```
?- connectRow(X, Y, 0).
true ;
(infinite loop)^CAction (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted

?- connectRow(X, Y, 2).
X = [spot(_G906, Y, _G908, _G909), spot(_G914, Y, _G916, _G917)|_G912] ;
(infinite loop)^CAction (h for help) ? abort
```

So there seem to be a few bugs here; if I were sure these were the whole story I would say:

- The base case should use the empty list rather than matching anything
- We should stipulate in the inductive case that K > 0
- We should use `clpfd` if we want to be able to generate all possibilities

Making the changes we get slightly different behavior:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

connectRow([], _, 0).
connectRow([spot(_, R, _, _)|Spots], R, K) :- 
  K #> 0, K1 #= K-1, connectRow(Spots, R, K1).

?- connectRow(X, Y, 0).
X = [] ;
false.

?- connectRow(X, Y, 1).
X = [spot(_G906, Y, _G908, _G909)] ;
false.

?- connectRow(X, Y, Z).
X = [],
Z = 0 ;

X = [spot(_G918, Y, _G920, _G921)],
Z = 1 ;

X = [spot(_G918, Y, _G920, _G921), spot(_G1218, Y, _G1220, _G1221)],
Z = 2
```

You'll note that in the result we have Y standing in our `spot` structures, but we have weird looking automatically generated variables in the other positions, such as `_G918`. As it happens, we could use `_` instead of Y and see a similar effect:

```
?- connectRow(X, _, Z).
X = [],
Z = 0 ;

X = [spot(_G1269, _G1184, _G1271, _G1272)],
Z = 1 ;

X = [spot(_G1269, _G1184, _G1271, _G1272), spot(_G1561, _G1184, _G1563, _G1564)],
Z = 2
```

All of these strange looking variables are there because we used `_`. Note that all of the `spot` structures have the exact same generated variable in the second position, because Prolog was told it had to unify the second parameter of `connectRow` with the second position of `spot`. It's true everywhere because R is "passed along" to the next call to connectRow, recursively.

Hopefully this helps explain what's going on with the `_` in your example, and also Prolog unification in general.

**Edit**: Unifying something with R

To answer your question below, you can unify R with a value directly, or by binding it to a variable and using the variable. For instance, we can bind it directly:

```
?- connectRow(X, 'Hello, world!', 2).
X = [spot(_G275, 'Hello, world!', _G277, _G278), spot(_G289, 'Hello, world!', _G291, _G292)]
```

We can also bind it and then assign it later:

```
?- connectRow(X, R, 2), R='Neato'.
X = [spot(_G21, 'Neato', _G23, _G24), spot(_G29, 'Neato', _G31, _G32)],
R = 'Neato'
```

There's nothing special about saying `R=<foo>`; it unifies both sides of the expression, but both sides can be expressions rather than variables:

```
?- V = [2,3], [X,Y,Z] = [1|V].
V = [2, 3],
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = 3.
```

So you can use R in another predicate just as well:

```
?- connectRow(X, R, 2), append([1,2], [3,4], R).
X = [spot(_G33, [1, 2, 3, 4], _G35, _G36), spot(_G41, [1, 2, 3, 4], _G43, _G44)],
R = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
```

Note that this creates opportunities for backtracking and generating other solutions. For instance:

```
?- connectRow(X, R, 2), length(R, _).
X = [spot(_G22, [], _G24, _G25), spot(_G30, [], _G32, _G33)],
R = [] ;

X = [spot(_G22, [_G35], _G24, _G25), spot(_G30, [_G35], _G32, _G33)],
R = [_G35] ;

X = [spot(_G22, [_G35, _G38], _G24, _G25), spot(_G30, [_G35, _G38], _G32, _G33)],
R = [_G35, _G38] ;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused about how this even works. 
I didn't think it would work without me specifying what that wildcard will be.
Could it be that it works because when it comes to the connectRow predicate it matches the wildcard with R?

Comment: Yes, it unifies the `_` with `R`. But unification in Prolog is pretty different from your standard argument passing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get this now. Can you expand on what you mean when you say it's different / send a link?

Comment: Well, starting from all variables in Prolog are uppercase, try running all five of these queries in your interpreter and seeing the effect will give you a good idea of what makes unification in Prolog different: `?- length([1,2,3], 3). ?- length([1,2,3], 2). ?- length([1,2,3], X). ?- length(X, 3). ?- length(X, Y).` I can expand on this with prose later tonight but that should whet your appetite.

Comment: @Shookie I have expanded on the prose, please let me know if there's anything I can elucidate further

Comment: Wow! Thank you! 
A few questions though:
So what you're saying is that, in my example above, I'm creating a list where that has the same structure (spot(_,_,R,_)) but doesn't unify the value of R with anything?
If I were to unify R with something, it would be in another predicate?

Comment: @Shookie I've added a section to try and expand on that.